# Virtual Box error "Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Hadoop" on MacOS Big Sur M1 chip

Tags: macos, big-sur, virtualbox, apple-silicon

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Hadoop.

The virtual machine 'Hadoop' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}

I tried the below things.

```
sudo su
csrutil clear
reboot
```

Uninstalling and then re-installing Virtual Box multiple times.
I did not receive any permission request to enable the blocked loading extensions in System preferences-->security.

```
csrutil enable 
reboot
```

I tried on a Mac intel chip 2017 and it runs perfectly fine.
Not sure what to change for the M1 chip here.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox does not run on an ARM chip such as the M1.
There's a long discussion on it here - https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=98742

Parallels have a functional beta & VMWare say there's one 'on the way' but as far as I know the only one that claims to be fully functional is [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app), which I haven't tried myself.
There's a setup guide on OWC's blog - [UTM: Run Virtual Machines On Your Apple Silicon M1 Mac](https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/72081-utm-virtual-machine-on-m1-mac/)